# How to reach JSON data inside parenthesis

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON response like this:

```
google.friendconnect.container["renderOpenSocialGadget"](
{

  height: 200,
  url: "http://username.github.io/",

  "view-params":  {"style":"light","url":"https://www.facebook.com/username","height":"258"},

  "prefs": {"style":"light","url":"https://www.facebook.com/username","height":"258"}

  }, skin);
```

I want to reach the values such as height, url, view-params but couldn't.
I tried this but it didn't worked:

```
console.log(google.friendconnect.container["renderOpenSocialGadget"].url);
```

Comment: @JeffMercado No matter if it is JSON or not, how can I get to the values inside parenthesis ?

Comment: @maskedmagician The best solution is probably to request JSON from the server. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't know too because this response from Google and I don't know why they use it. @MaximillianLaumeister Unfortunately I can't.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `google.friendconnect.container["renderOpenSocialGadget"](` is equivalent to `google.friendconnect.container.renderOpenSocialGadget(`

Given that, we see that this is a method of an object, getting a JSON object and an additional parameter (`skin`) as parameters.

As the object is somehow "anonymous" parsed directly in to the function call, you can't access it anymore, once the function has consumed it.

Check, if `google.friendconnect.container` has getter methods (they usually have ...) by `console.log(google.friendconnect.container)`.

**EDIT**

Just an Idea: you might catch the call and pass it over:

```
google.friendconnect.container["MyrenderOpenSocialGadget"] = 
      google.friendconnect.container["renderOpenSocialGadget"];

google.friendconnect.container["renderOpenSocialGadget"] = function(obj, skin) {

     // do what you want with obj
     console.log(obj.url);

     //call original
     google.friendconnect.container["MyrenderOpenSocialGadget"](obj, skin);

});
```

Comment: @maskedmagician Bit more complicated, but doesn't make any difference.